# Prevent HTML table from overflowing the containing div

Tags: html, css, html-table

My objective is to have a layout that has a fixed area at the top, then a table (with scrollbars) in the remaining available area. I've simplified this for the benefit of asking this question.

I've tried to do this by having a div of a specific size (in this example 300x300 pixels) shown in the example as cyan, this contains a table with two rows, the top one containing the header, then the second one containing a div, which in turn contains the table with the data I want to scroll through.

```css
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
table,th,td {border: 1px solid gray;}
table.nowrap {white-space: nowrap;}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="width:300px; height:300px; background-color: cyan;">
            <table>
                <tr style="height:40px;background-color: lightblue;">
                    <td>This is the static header</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div style='width:100%; height:100%; overflow:scroll;'>
                            <table class='nowrap'>
                                <tr><td>An item in the table</td><td>An item in the table</td><td>An item in the table</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>An item in the table</td><td>An item in the table</td><td>An item in the table</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>An item in the table</td><td>An item in the table</td><td>An item in the table</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>An item in the table</td><td>An item in the table</td><td>An item in the table</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>An item in the table</td><td>An item in the table</td><td>An item in the table</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>An item in the table</td><td>An item in the table</td><td>An item in the table</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>An item in the table</td><td>An item in the table</td><td>An item in the table</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>An item in the table</td><td>An item in the table</td><td>An item in the table</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>An item in the table</td><td>An item in the table</td><td>An item in the table</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>An item in the table</td><td>An item in the table</td><td>An item in the table</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>An item in the table</td><td>An item in the table</td><td>An item in the table</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>An item in the table</td><td>An item in the table</td><td>An item in the table</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>An item in the table</td><td>An item in the table</td><td>An item in the table</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>An item in the table</td><td>An item in the table</td><td>An item in the table</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>An item in the table</td><td>An item in the table</td><td>An item in the table</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>An item in the table</td><td>An item in the table</td><td>An item in the table</td></tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

If you run this, it shows the following, but I don't understand why. The  height/width are 100%, so shouldn't it inherit the size from the parent?

[image: Shows full table]

If I change the line

```
<div style='width:100%; height:100%; overflow:scroll;'>
```

to

```
<div style='width:300px; height:260px; overflow:scroll;'>
```

Then it displays the scrollable table within the `div`.. which is correct (or at least what I want). But I won't know the exact size, as the screen is built dynamically, and on different browsers etc.

[image: How I want it to appear]

So, if I specify the exact width of the div (within the `td`) rather than a percentage, it works fine - could it be picking up the size from another parent rather than the outer `div`?

Comment: if I were you I would use a viewport

Comment: Your nowrap rule is pushing the table outside the div

Comment: But I want the table to be larger than the div, so that it shows the scrollbars. if I omit the `nowrap` it squashes everything in so that it fits.. which looks horrible

Comment: @RichS do you want something like this? [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/02wk3eaq/)

Comment: @xmaster - I've added an image to my original post showing what I want, which I CAN get using the exact pixels, but not a %

Comment: @RichS but what is wrong with mine?

Comment: in your fiddle, it shows the full table without scroll bars. I want to specify the size of the container, and have the scrollable table within this.

Comment: @RichS you mean in full screen?

Comment: @xmaster - I've put everything in a `div` measuring 300x300, in reality, this will be different, but I need the content to scroll if it's bigger than the container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is many better ways than using table to do this but i will fit to your method.

This is the whole html code that will get the wanted result (Just read the comments to see the changes):

```html
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Table</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }

            table,
            th,
            td {
                border: 1px solid gray;
            }

            table.nowrap {
                white-space: nowrap;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- Added position:relative to the div -->
        <div style="width:300px;position: relative;height:300px;background-color: cyan;">

            <!-- Change the table position to absolute and make its width and height 100% of the parent's -->
            <table style="position: absolute;width: 100%;height: 100%;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr style="height:40px;background-color: lightblue;">
                        <td>This is the static header</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                         <!-- Added position:relative to the cell so the div will fit to it -->
                        <td style="position: relative;">
                            <!-- Make the div position absolute and position it to the top of the cell -->
                            <div style="position: absolute;top: 0;width:100%;height:100%;overflow:auto;">
                                <!--Set width and height to 100% so it will always fill the div-->
                                <table class="nowrap" style="width:100%;height:100%">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                            <td>An item in the table</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: looking good so far, just trying to understand what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: By looking to your question, i can assume you are somehow a beginner so i'll advice you to try to play with the inspect tool (F12) in your browser and try different values there.